# Pytorch - Convert a list of numpy array to a list of tensor

Tags: python, arrays, pytorch, tensor

I have a list of numpy array. Is there a quick way to convert them into tensor in Pytorch? I know I can do it simply using a for loop. But are there any other ways to do so?

Comment: It's only a slight improvement over a for loop, but you could use a list comprehension.

Comment: Show the loop code